# Displayport dual panel external display issues

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

Platform: Jetson Xavier JEtpack 4.1 (
    L4T R31.1
    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS aarch64
    CUDA 10.0.117

I am trying to connect a displayport output using the USB-C Alt mode. I have a USB-C to Displayport adapter and then a DP to mDP cable going to a 2 panel display but only one panel shows an image. 2880x1600 90Hz

[Half Display visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk10c.jpg)

The output of xrandr shows the display is connected and lists the expected resolution as selected.

[xrandr output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGsnU.jpg)

I've also tried a USB-C to mDP cable and both displays will flicker but have an image displayed. Both cables are 2 m, so I am looking to find a 1m version to try as well.

What are some other troubleshooting steps I can take?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. You should edit your post so that the images are displayed instead of just linked to. to do this press edit and then click on the image button,  then drag and drop your images form your computer to the box that pops up. you won't be able to use the current links as that site format is not supported.